# passing a value to call-button in android

Tags: android

i am creating a calling application . I am trying to use a default number in actionView and want to pass a mobile number in mobile call button.

this is my code:-

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
                  // this is real calling number 
        long mobile = "tel:9999999999";
                                           // this is default number.and show in textfield of calling.
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:+919910699440");
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        // here i want to pass real calling num in Button. so when i press the                         
                    //calling button . button will get mobile num but not show.     

                     intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+mobile));

                 startActivity(intent);


                }
```

thank you for your time.

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to display a number but call another. I think this is not possibile.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the following code you can call **`ACTION_CALL Intent`**

```
int Number = 0377778888;
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

and you also need to add this permission to the AndroidManifest File

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- use `Intent.ACTION_CALL`:

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number.trim()));
  startActivity(intent);
  ```

  This will effectively call the supplied `number` phone number. Just remember that this action requires the `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` permission in the manifest:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
  ```
- use `Intent.ACTION_DIAL`:

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number.trim()));
  startActivity(intent);
  ```

  This shows the dialer view with the `number` already dialed in, but allows the user to decide to actually make the call or not. This does *not* require additional permissions.

Comment: thank 4 reply, your second ans :- When this shows dialer view with number and allows the user to decide to actually make the call then user press the call button and get the hide mobile number value. is it possible to get mobile number and user can not view the number .

Comment: @RahulRawat no, that is an outside application not controlled by you. you can't make fake- or bogus- calls.

Comment: i m working in a webservice application. When i opened callme4.com in webbrowser of mobile and login. i reached any one user add like as "purchase car" and there is a "call this user" button . i clicked on it by mobile browser open. and got a default phone number in my android phone and when i made a call , i found this was not actully number of user . i am also want to make such type application in android .  is it possible? please

Comment: I'm sorry.. I don't understand what you actually want to achieve. Maybe try expanding your question using images and examples..

Comment: thank you for looking it . i will give u details of this . currently working to complete websevice . when it will complete with login user . i will give you login and password with details of each step . you will see How this is working for calling. thankx

Answer (score 1):

Try this code I changed this code:

```
 no=txt_no.getText().toString().trim();

   String URI_TEL = "tel";
           Uri uri = Uri.fromParts(URI_TEL, no, null);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,uri);
            //intent.setData(Uri.parse(no));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: there is run time exception :- Instrumentation.checkstartactivityResult(int, object) and this is logcat:- 01-28 16:18:38.043: W/ThrottleService(93): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0

Comment: you use this code final String URI_TEL = "tel"; this will help to you "tel" is a default activity.

Comment: I will edit the code above use it and let you know the outcome

Comment: finally thank  U for help me . i got solution . my database is PBX and this provide us a default number. we just need to insert some data in PBX database's table. and it give us result 1 (one) or true. and we use this default number for making call. this number is provide by PBX. and internally this number has real mobile number but it is not show us . it is AMAZING WORK OF "PBX" database of mysql. thank you all of you